# Why is gulp complaining about Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am writting a gulp tasks where I take several js file , concat them , minify those.. same with scss into css etc ...normal stuffs

And, it is for Drupal 8

Here is my gulpfile. However on running this, I keep on getting the following error:

```
[10:00:58] Starting 'scripts'...

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/novaent/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1255:21)
'use strict';
```

And below is my gulp file

```
// Include gulp.
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var config = require('./config.json');

// Include plugins.
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngcrush = require('imagemin-pngcrush');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var glob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


// sassOptions are optional but things like sourceComments (line_comments) can be pretty handy.
var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  sourceComments: 'line_comments',
  includePaths: config.css.includePaths
};


// CSS.
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.css.src)
    .pipe(glob())
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        notify.onError({
          title: 'Gulp',
          subtitle: 'Failure!',
          message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>',
          sound: 'Beep'
        })(error);
        this.emit('end');
      }}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9', 'ie 10'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true, injectChanges: true, match: '**/*.css'}));
});

// Compress images.
gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.images.src)
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
      use: [pngcrush()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images.dest));
});

// Fonts.
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.fonts.src)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.fonts.dest));
});

// javaScripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.js.src)
    .pipe(concat('index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.dest)) // outputs *.js without min
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.dest)) // outputs *.js.min
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Rebuild all custom scripts'}));
});

// Watch task.
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(config.css.src, ['css']);
  gulp.watch(config.fonts.src, ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch(config.js.src, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(config.images.src, ['images']);
});

// Static Server + Watch
gulp.task('serve', ['css', 'fonts', 'watch'], function () {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: config.proxy
  });
});

// Run drush to clear the theme registry.
gulp.task('drush', shell.task([
  'drush cache-clear theme-registry'
]));

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: You've gotten it into an infinitely recursive call. Don't know why yet, though.

Comment: Yeah, RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  possibly indicating recursive call on the js.. But it should not right?

Comment: You'd think so, but `uglify` goes there. Not sure why. Are you supposed to pass something in to the call? Never done that with gulp, so I'm not sure.

Comment: no no that I can think off

Comment: Yeah, I checked the docs and `uglify()` seems to be the way to do it. Dunno, maybe one of the preceeding `pipe`s makes too many files for uglify to process? Well, either that or it chokes on some JS that takes too much calls to process. Try removing/changing some of the preceeding calls, to see if it is a problem, but also try to run the processess manually from the command line and see if it's just `uglify` getting stuck on some code. See if you can narrow it down to a particular file or something. Note that the file might be fine by itself but problematic when combined with others.

Comment: I think I have solved it. The uglify minified file was in the same folder from where the custom js files were. I was asking to check the same folder, concat + minify and dump it in the same folder.. It does smell like recursiveness to me :)

Answer (score -5):

I think I have solved it as below

```
'use strict';

// Include gulp.
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var config = require('./config.json');

// Include plugins.
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngcrush = require('imagemin-pngcrush');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var glob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed',
  sourceComments: 'line_comments',
  includePaths: config.css.includePaths
};


var uglifyOptions = {
  preserveComments: 'license',
  warnings: 'true'
};

// CSS.
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.css.src)
    .pipe(glob())
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        notify.onError({
          title: 'Gulp',
          subtitle: 'Failure!',
          message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>',
          sound: 'Beep'
        })(error);
        this.emit('end');
      }}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 9', 'ie 10'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true, injectChanges: true, match: '**/*.css'}));
});

// Compress images.
gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.images.src)
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
      use: [pngcrush()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images.dest));
});

// Fonts.
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.fonts.src)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.fonts.dest));
});


// Concat all js files into one index.min.js file
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.js.src)
    .pipe(concat('./js/index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify(uglifyOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/dist/'))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Rebuild all custom scripts. Please refresh your browser'}));
});

// Watch task.
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(config.css.src, ['css']);
  gulp.watch(config.fonts.src, ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch(config.js.src, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(config.images.src, ['images']);
});

// Static Server + Watch
gulp.task('serve', ['css', 'fonts', 'scripts', 'watch'], function () {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: config.proxy
  });
});

// Run drush to clear the theme registry.
gulp.task('drush', shell.task([
  'drush cache-clear theme-registry'
]));

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: This is not useful unless you explain what exactly you have changed and why it caused issues.

Comment: Actually I have written in the comments above.  
I think I have solved it. The uglify minified file was in the same folder from where the custom js files were. I was asking to check the same folder, concat + minify and dump it in the same folder.. It does smell like recursiveness to me :)